# Is there a way to fade just the text of a div when the div has a partially transparent background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a "Read More" fade effect on text when it overflows its container. It is easy when the text is on a solid background. You can have an overlay div with a linear gradient transparency in the same color as the background.This makes it look the text is fading into the background

However my text is already on a partially transparent background. The transparency of the overlay stacks on top of the background making the background appear to fade along with the text. Here is a js fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/b0p6Lozv/2/

My desired effect is to have the background color be consistent throughout the div and have the text fade out towards the bottom of the div. Is it possible to create a gradient on just the foreground colors of a div? Thanks for the help!

here is the code

```html
<div class="pageBody">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='container'>
    <p>line1</p>
    <p>line2</p>
    <p>line3 line3 line3 line3</p>
    <p>line4</p>
   </div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pageBody">
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class='container'>
    <p>line1</p>
    <p>line2</p>
    <p>line3 line3 line3 line3</p>
    <p>line4</p>
   </div>
  <div class="overlay2">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.pageBody {
  background: black;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use HTML5?

Get rid of the overlay div and just CSS style the .container div.

You could use a clipping-path or mask.

Mask

```
.container {
etc...
mask: url(mask.svg) top left / cover;
}
```

Clipping Path

```
.container {
etc...  
  clip-path: url(#clippingPathImage);
}
```

> The clip-path property can be applied to all HTML elements... a clipPath element or one of the basic shapes introduced with CSS Exclusions.

More info:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: This looks promising but unfortunately we are still looking to support IE11 which does not support clip-path or mask

Answer (score 0):

> My desired effect is to have the background color be consistent
>   throughout the div and have the text fade out towards the bottom of
>   the div. Is it possible to create a gradient on just the foreground
>   colors of a div?

If you want the foreground color to fade over a series of consecutive paragraphs, yes.

You can do it using the alpha-channel transparency of the `rgba` color format:

```css
.container p:nth-last-of-type(3) {
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.container p:nth-last-of-type(2) {
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.container p:nth-last-of-type(1) {
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<p>line1</p>
<p>line2</p>
<p>line3 line3 line3 line3</p>
<p>line4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not general enough for my needs as the cutoff where the fade needs to happen wont be correlated with any element tags